# WP Customer Reviews call short code on another page

Tags: plugins, themes, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, templates

I have created some theme page and I want to call [WP Customer Reviews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/) shortcode

```
 echo do_shortcode('[WPCR_SHOW POSTID="' . $post->ID . '" NUM="1" HIDEREVIEWS="0" HIDERESPONSE="1" HIDECUSTOM="1" SHOWFORM="0"]');
```

but it returns

> [WPCR_SHOW POSTID="3498" NUM="1" HIDEREVIEWS="0" HIDERESPONSE="1"
>   HIDECUSTOM="1" SHOWFORM="0"]

Here is my full source code.
File is in ***wp-content\themes\couponxl - child\category_details.php***

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Category Details */
get_header();
$search_sidebar_location = couponxl_get_option('search_sidebar_location');

if ($_GET['paged']) {
    $cur_page = $_GET['paged'];
    $offset = $_GET['paged'] * 4;
} else {
    $cur_page = 1;
    $offset = 1;
}

get_template_part('includes/title');
?>
<section>
    <div class="container">

        <?php
        $content = get_the_content();
        if (!empty($content)):
            ?>
            <div class="white-block">
                <div class="white-block-content">
                    <div class="page-content clearfix">
                        <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        endif;
        ?>

        <div class="row">

            <?php if ($search_sidebar_location == 'left'): ?>
                <?php get_sidebar('coupon') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="col-md-<?php echo is_active_sidebar('sidebar-coupon') ? '9' : '12' ?>">
                <?php echo do_shortcode("[wcps id='3414']"); ?>
                <div class="row masonry masonry-item">
                    <?php
                    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                        'paged' => $cur_page, 'post_type' => 'product', 'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $_GET['cat'], // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                            )
                    ));
                    $postslist = new WP_Query($args);
                    $coupons = $postslist;
                    $page_links_total = $coupons->max_num_pages;
                    $pagination_args = array(
                        'prev_next' => true,
                        'total' => $page_links_total,
                        'current' => $cur_page,
                        'prev_next' => true,
                        'type' => 'array',
                    );

                    $pagination_args['format'] = '?paged=%#%';

                    $page_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);
                    $pagination = couponxl_format_pagination($page_links);

                    if (!empty($postslist->posts)) {
                        foreach ($postslist->posts as $post) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="white-block offer-box coupon-box <?php echo esc_attr($offer_view) ?> <?php echo $col == '12' ? 'clearfix' : '' ?>">
                                <div class="col-md-6 product-list">
                                    <div class="white-block-media <?php echo $col == '12' ? 'col-sm-4' : '' ?>">
                                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 ">
                                            <?php
                                            $store_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'location', true);
                                            couponxl_store_logo($store_id);
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php if (couponxl_is_plugin_active('couponxl-cpt/couponxl-cpt.php')) : ?>
                                            <?php couponxl_cpt_share(); ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?> 
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    echo '<label class="flag-new">' . $label = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'label', true) . '</label>';
                                    echo '<label class="flag-discount" style="color: #f32398;">-' . $discount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'discount', true) . '%</label>';
                                    echo '<label class="wishlist-button">' . do_shortcode('[woosw id = ' . $post->ID . ']') . '</label>';
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="white-block-content <?php echo $col == '12' ? 'col-sm-8' : '' ?>">
                                        <?php
                                        echo do_shortcode('[WPCR_SHOW POSTID="'.$post->ID.'" NUM="1" HIDEREVIEWS="0" HIDERESPONSE="1" HIDECUSTOM="1" SHOWFORM="0"]');
                                        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expires_in', true)) {
                                            $earlier = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
                                            $later = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expires_in', true))));
                                            $diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");
                                            if (!empty($diff)) {
                                                echo '<span class="expire-date">Expires in: <span class="expire-text">' . $diff . ' days</span></span>';
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<span class="expire-date"> </span>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <h3>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </h3>

                                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline bottom-meta">

                                            <li>
                                                <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o icon-margin"></i>
                                                <?php echo couponxl_taxonomy('product_cat', 1) ?>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker icon-margin"></i> 
                                                <?php echo couponxl_taxonomy('location', 1) ?>
                                            </li>               

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="white-block-footer  <?php echo $col == '12' ? 'col-sm-12' : '' ?>">
                                        <div class="white-block-content">
                                            <?php
                                            $price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
                                            $sale = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
                                            ?>

                                            <?php if ($sale) : ?>
                                                <span class="price-style">
                                                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                                        <i class="">RM</i><?php echo $sale; ?>
                                                        <i class="fa">RM</i>
                                                        <del><?php echo $price; ?></del> 
                                                    </span>    
                                                </span>    
                                            <?php elseif ($price) : ?>
                                                <span class="price-style">
                                                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                                        <i class="fa">RM</i> <?php
                                                        echo $price;
                                                        ?>    
                                                    </span>    
                                                </span>    
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <span class="span-class1">
                                                <a class="btn single_add_to_cart_button alt" href="<?= site_url() . '/cart/?add-to-cart=' . $post->ID ?>">Add to cart</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="white-block-content">
                                <p class="nothing-found">Currently there is no products for this category.</p>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php //endif;              ?>
        </div>
        <?php if (!empty($pagination)): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 masonry-item paginate">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have already enabled WP Customer Reviews for that product.

[image]

Can anyone help me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to use that plugin on any page you wanted to.

Create a function in your theme/function.php

```
function get_review_rating($id = null) {
    $id = $id['id'];
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/wp-customer-reviews-3.php' );
    $WPCustomerReviews31 = new WPCustomerReviews3();
    $WPCustomerReviews31->start();
        $WPCustomerReviews31->init();
    echo do_shortcode('[WPCR_SHOW POSTID=' . $id . ' NUM="1" HIDEREVIEWS="0" HIDERESPONSE="1" HIDECUSTOM="1" SHOWFORM="0"]');
//    die;
}

add_shortcode('get_review_and_rating', 'get_review_rating');
```

Now instead of calling plugin default shortcode call `get_review_and_rating` shortcode anywhere, you wanted to.

```
echo do_shortcode('[get_review_and_rating id='.$post->ID.']');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, it should output reviews for the specified ID. I have used the same shortcode and it works.

The reason it returns the shortcode text can be because you **haven't activated WP Customer Reviews plugin**.

- check whether the plugin is active or not?

Comment: The plugin is already activated and working only if content is from page or post, not on template page.